# Android ant build.xml with proguard does not build in release

Tags: android, ant, build, release, proguard

I have the following  project setup:
Two libraries 'commoncomponents' and 'libs' that both have some activities defined e.g. with a webview and dialog helper classes.
Then there is my 'application library' which contains the app code which in turn is 
referenced by the App 'Free' and the App 'Full'.

I have enabled proguard with the following additional entry

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

However the build process fails when launching ant with the release target and proguard 
complains that the R$string classes are missing

If I call 'ant release' on 'commoncomponents', 'libs' or 'application library' projects proguard succeeds,
But when I launch it on either the 'app free' or 'app full' this errormessage is comes up:

```
         [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: ~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/bin/classes
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for bin...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
-pre-build:
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] Found 2 AIDL files.
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Build type changed: Generating new BuildConfig class.
-pre-compile:
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 12 source files to ~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/bin/classes
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: ~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/bin/classes.jar
-post-compile:
-obfuscate:
   [delete] Deleting: ~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/bin/proguard/original.jar
      [jar] Building jar: ~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/bin/proguard/original.jar
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 4.7
 [proguard] Reading input...
 [proguard] Reading program jar [~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/bin/proguard/original.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/CommonComponents/bin/classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/exampleLib/bin/classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/Bfw/bin/classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/Developer/Java/android-sdk-macosx/tools/support/annotations.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [~/Workspace/Workspaces/workspace-indigo/MyApp/libs/android-support-v4.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [/Developer/Java/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-10/android.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [/Developer/Java/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-real3d-lge-10/libs/real3d.jar]
 [proguard] Initializing...
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.ApplicationBase: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.HelpDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.HelpDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.HelpDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$layout
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$id
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$layout
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$id
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog$1: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog$1: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R$string
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.common.WebDialog$1: can't find referenced class com.example.common.R
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.dlg.InfoDialogActivity: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$layout
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.dlg.InfoDialogActivity: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R$layout
 [proguard] Warning: com.example.dlg.InfoDialogActivity: can't find referenced class com.example.lib.R
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
 [proguard] Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
 [proguard]       You should check your configuration for typos.
 [proguard] Warning: there were 23 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

BUILD FAILED
/Developer/Java/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:570: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/Java/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:834: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

The project setup seems ok to me, since 'ant debug' compiles without errors.
The package name was changed to com.example and my user dir to ~/xy in the listing above

I've searched the web for the issue and I found a lot of posts especially here on stackoverflow, but none helped me solve the issue yet, hope someone is so kind to assist although this is my very first question.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the application library build file had the proguard obfuscation switched on, by switching it off all symbols were found when building the free and full application stubs.